# How to call a google custom search web service from trigger and parse the response to save in my sObject

Tags: salesforce

```
global class CalloutSevicesQuery implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.AllowsCallouts{
    Public String Query;
    Public String ID;
    public string Body;
    global  CalloutSevicesQuery(String QueryID)
    {
        ID = QueryID;
    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {
           Query='SELECT id, BodyTxt__c,SubjectTxt__c FROM CustomEmailObj__c where id =:ID';
           return Database.getQueryLocator(Query);

    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,List<CustomEmailObj__c> CusEmail)
    {

        String url = 'http://google.com/#q=';

        for(CustomEmailObj__c C : CusEmail){
        Body=C.BodyTxt__c;   
        System.debug('333'+Body);
        }
        Body= EncodingUtil.urlEncode(Body, 'UTF-8');
        // build callout
        url += Body; 
        Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(url);
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setTimeout(60000);
       // system.debug('!2222'+req);

        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);

       Integer statusCode = res.getStatusCode();
      // system.debug('!1111'+statusCode);
       String statusName = res.getStatus();
       //system.debug('!33333'+statusName);

    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {

    }

}
```

what endpoint **url** i should use in this? Because right now i am getting `status 301.`
I want to **parse** string stored in body variable to google search engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it works with:

```
https://www.google.com
```

and of course you have to set this endpoint also in the remote site settings
If I execute the following code in the developer console:

```
String url = 'https://www.google.com/#q=';
String body = 'hallo';
url += Body; 
Http h = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint(url);
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setTimeout(60000);
HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
Integer statusCode = res.getStatusCode();
system.debug(statusCode);
String statusName = res.getStatus();
system.debug(statusName);
```

The result is:

```
Debug | 200
Debug | OK
```

Comment: i am also adding url like this: 'https://www.google.co.in/#q=facebook';     and in response i should get all link related to facebook but i am getting only links related to google like google map, youtube,gmail etc.. why so ???

Comment: Did you get the response related to 'Hallo' after execution and in which format?

Comment: The response if I use the res.getBody() method is the whole site in html.

Comment: i am also adding url like this: 'google.co.in/#q=facebook';; and in response i should get all link related to facebook but i am getting only links related to google like google map, youtube,gmail etc.. why so ???

Comment: You can try it with:
`https://www.google.com/search?q`
This works and you get the results for your query but again in html